# Camera plugin - Cannot crop gallery pictures

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins

Working with [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)

I have a mobile application where I want the user to take a picture or choose one from their saved photo album.

Now both of these functionalities work. The problem is in the saved photo album.

To prevent a squished image I have set `allowEdit` to `true` to basically force a square picture instead of rectangle. This works well when a picture is taken with the camera but doesn't work for the saved photo album.

(**seeing the gridline - cropping tool**)

Is there an option/workaround to fix this?

*(note I know about the common memory problem when using `DATA_URL` but it's required)*

```
 /** takeImage - changes the image of a participant to a file from the camera */
    changePicture(type: string) {
        // processing might take a while, set up loading message
        let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
            content: 'Processing...',
            spinner: 'crescent'
        });
        // set the phototype (make photo from camera or choose from gallery)
        let photoType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        if(type === 'gallery') {
            photoType = Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM;
        }
        // setting up the options
        Camera.getPicture({
            quality: 85,    // 85% to reduce size
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, // returns a base64 string
            sourceType: photoType, // source type mentioned above
            allowEdit: true, // allows us to crop the picture (force square) <-- doesnt work on SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
            saveToPhotoAlbum: true, // saving the created photo to album (reusability)
            correctOrientation: true, // allow the user to rotate the image
            targetWidth: 200,
            targetHeight: 200
        }).then((imageData) => {
            loading.present();
            // change the image for every user
            this.apiCaller.changeImage(this.participant.id, imageData).subscribe(response => {
                // set the participant's base64image so it will be updated in the view
                this.participant.base64image = imageData;
                loading.dismiss();
            });
        }, err => {
            alert(err);
        });
    }
```

Comment: your `allowEdit: true` will work only after you take the picture from your app before saving it. if you want edit the image that have been save then you have choose the app that will help the picture to edit like open the app inside the galary app that will help your picture to be editable

Comment: does it happen on iOS? Android? both?

Comment: Dont have ios to test one so I do not know, at least it happens on android